# What is 'assert' in a kernel module?

Tags: freebsd, kernel-module

I am developing a kernel module.  In the event specific errors occur I want to break into the debugger or otherwise stop execution.

How can I conditionally trigger an error condition

- which is removed when optimization are enabled

and

- which is not removed when optimization are enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use KASSERT.  It's slightly different from userspace assert(); use it like this:

KASSERT(x == y, ("%s: %d != %d", **func**, x, y));

KASSERTs are enabled if INVARIANTS option is defined in the kernel config.  In 11-CURRENT it's enabled by default; in stable releases it's disabled.